# Access VBA Copy From Recordset Range Object Error -2147417856

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, vba

My database uses an ODBC connection to connect to SQL server.

The access code runs through a SQL table of 100,000 years (around 5.7 million rows) and spits out in increments of 10,000 years data that is then run through a macro in excel and then repeated for the next increment of 10k years.

The first set of 10,000 years has roughly 420k+ rows exporting to excel
The next set of 10,000 years (years 10,001-20,000) has roughly 450k+ rows

Assume gradual increase of 30k rows per 10k year jump up

When getting to the 60,001-70,000 increment sometimes the code will crap out and give a

> 'Copy from Recordset Object Range Method failed Code -2147417856' error

The fix to this is to hit debug, then just hit the play button and the code then continues. Because that fix works, I'm under the impression that access is getting overloaded with processing and just craps out randomly (I don't know what else could be wrong)

I tried to install an error handling fix to repeat the part of the code that craps out if an error occurs, and the error handler caught the error, but the error still occurred.

UPDATE: Before I typed this up I went into the Excel file that is being spit out and hit Ctrl + Pause within the macro and then hit the play button then hit Ctrl + Pause again then hit the play button. Then I pressed debug and clicked compile VBA project and then saved the workbook. Then when running from access again there was no error.

Honestly, I have no idea what's going on so any ideas or fixes on this would be helpful. (Although it seems as if I have fixed the issue)

Comment: Look at using `DoEvents` it might clear down some pending messages in the processing queue

Comment: Are you using ADO or DAO to open the recordset? There's a screwy bug in ADO that causes all sorts of weird memory issues when you use certain kinds of cursor/command combinations (asynchfetch + forwardonly, for example). Certain specific data sets seem to trigger it. *Probably* unrelated, but if that sounds like it may apply, change your cursor to `adOpenKeyset` and your execute option to synchronous (`&H0`) see if that fixes it.

Comment: So this error says its an object, what is the `object`? Can it be replaced by `application`?